# How to use jQuery to filter a bootstrap table by particular columns only

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

There is a very pithy method for bootstrap table filtering on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_filters_table&stacked=h

Here is the jQuery/Javascript portion (uses a text box to filter the table):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

However, the example table provided has three columns (first name, last name, e-mail), and this will search all three.  I would like a very simple way to refine this to search only a particular column (e.g. e-mail only) or only two of the columns (e.g. first name and last name only).  I can see some much lengthier ideas in other answers, but since this looks so straightforward, I though I might ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select `td` for which you want to search. You can use below code if you want to search in first or last `td` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {     
      $(this).toggle($(this).find("td:first").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

You can use `:last` to select last element if needed. If you want to select second element then you can use `eq` selectore as well as `find("td:eq(1)")`.

If you want to apply search for two columns, you can simply copy the search selector in find as  `find("td:eq(0),td:eq(2)")` which will search in First and Last column.

Thanks and hopefully it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your filter function to this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).find('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@mail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Anja</td>
        <td>Ravendale</td>
        <td>a_r@test.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

With `find('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)')` you can search by first and second columns. Change the condition to whatever it suites you. If you want to search only by email (3rd column), the condition will be `find('td:eq(2)')`